# How to select all subjects that are taken by all students such that all students took grade > 50 in them

Tags: mysql

I have a table called records containing 3 columns: student, subject and grade

Each {x,y,z} entry in the table means student x took class y with grade z. If student x didn't take class y then the entry doesn't exist in the table. So this table is like a university record of all students and the subjects taken by them.

I want to select all subjects that are taken by all students such that the grades of all students in these subjects are above 60.

I tried creating the table

```
CREATE TABLE temp SELECT subject FROM records WHERE grade > 60;
```

Then I used temp to create a new table that has subject and count, where count counts the number of students that took that subject, and then I deleted all rows that have count< number of students. But I know this is very inefficient.

How can I do this more efficiently using MySQL ?
Also if you can provide me with good MySQL resource/tutorial link so that I can practice, I would be thankful. I am new to MySQL and I am working on large databases and I need to make my queries more efficient and straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT subject FROM records 
WHERE subject NOT IN
(
SELECT subject FROM records 
WHERE grade <=60
)
AND subject IN
(
SELECT subject FROM records
GROUP BY subject
HAVING count(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT student) FROM records)
)
```

As further reading I'd recommend [this](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-in.php) and [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

EDITED: now includes "subjects taken by ALL students"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, One problem with this approach is that if a subject is not taken by everyone but taken by few students and this small group of students got >= 60 then this subject will show up in this query but I do not want that.

Comment: I understand. Define "small group" and i'll update. Or do you want the subject to be taken by ALL students?

Comment: I want the subject to be taken by all students

Comment: Done. Edited answer. Worked on the test SQL fiddle i set up.

Comment: PS - if table has or will have a large number of rows, check performance against using EXISTS / NOT EXISTS instead of IN / NOT IN.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the no exists clause because it simply confirms if there are no records within the subquery, but will not try to obtain the resultset. It is more effective than a not in clause.

```
SELECT subject FROM records r1
WHERE subject NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 1 FROM records r2 
WHERE r2.subject=r1.SUBJECT AND grade<=60
)
```